# Request hibernate with @EmbeddedId not working (Spring boot - 2.3.1.RELEASE)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm blocked in my project. I can't get sql queries to work with the class that's "@Embeddable."
I have a class "User" which have multiple "Preference"

```
package com.donation.rest.model;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.CollectionTable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Convert;
import javax.persistence.ElementCollection;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;

import com.donation.rest.converter.RightConverter;
import com.donation.rest.dto.UserDTO;
import com.donation.rest.enums.RightsEnum;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User extends DateModel implements IModel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6678092850253642056L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "USER_ID", unique = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "USER_NAME", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "USER_PASSWORD", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @ElementCollection(targetClass = RightsEnum.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "users_rights", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID"))
    @Column(name = "RIGHTS", nullable = false)
    @Convert(converter = RightConverter.class)
    private Set<RightsEnum> rights = new HashSet<RightsEnum>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "preferenceId.user", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private Set<Preference> preferences = new HashSet<Preference>();

    public User() {
        super();
    }

    public User(Long id, String name, String password, Set<RightsEnum> rights, Set<Preference> preferences) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
        this.rights = rights;
        this.preferences = preferences;
    }

    public User(UserDTO userDTO) {
        this.setName(userDTO.getName());
        this.setPassword(userDTO.getPassword());
        this.setRights(userDTO.getRights());
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Set<RightsEnum> getRights() {
        return rights;
    }

    public void setRights(Set<RightsEnum> rights) {
        this.rights = rights;
    }

    public Set<Preference> getPreferences() {
        return preferences;
    }

    public void setPreferences(Set<Preference> preferences) {
        this.preferences = preferences;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", password=" + password + ", rights=" + rights + ", preferences="
                + preferences + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = super.hashCode();
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((password == null) ? 0 : password.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (!super.equals(obj))
            return false;
        if (!(obj instanceof User))
            return false;
        User other = (User) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.getId() != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.getId()))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

I have the class "Preference" which use two primary key : an user and a key (enum). So I use the annotation @EmbeddedId and declare PreferenceId.

```
package com.donation.rest.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;

@Entity
@Table(name = "preferences")
public class Preference implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6320680839053872351L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private PreferenceId preferenceId;

    @Column(name = "PREFERENCE_VALUE", nullable = false)
    @Type(type = "text")
    private String value;

    public Preference() {
        super();
    }

    public Preference(PreferenceId preferenceId, String value) {
        super();
        this.preferenceId = preferenceId;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public PreferenceId getPreferenceId() {
        return preferenceId;
    }

    public void setPreferenceId(PreferenceId preferenceId) {
        this.preferenceId = preferenceId;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Preference [preferenceId=" + preferenceId + ", value=" + value + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((preferenceId == null) ? 0 : preferenceId.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((value == null) ? 0 : value.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Preference other = (Preference) obj;
        if (preferenceId == null) {
            if (other.preferenceId != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!preferenceId.equals(other.preferenceId))
            return false;
        if (value == null) {
            if (other.value != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!value.equals(other.value))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

Then, the class "PreferenceId" which is "@Embeddable".

```
package com.donation.rest.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

import com.donation.rest.enums.PreferencesEnum;

@Embeddable
public class PreferenceId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5641070814677067804L;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", nullable = false)
    private User user;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "PREFERENCE_KEY", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private PreferencesEnum key;

    public PreferenceId() {
        super();
    }

    public PreferenceId(User user, PreferencesEnum key) {
        super();
        this.user = user;
        this.key = key;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public PreferencesEnum getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(PreferencesEnum key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PreferenceId [user=" + user + ", key=" + key + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((key == null) ? 0 : key.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((user == null) ? 0 : user.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        PreferenceId other = (PreferenceId) obj;
        if (key != other.key)
            return false;
        if (user == null) {
            if (other.user != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!user.equals(other.user))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

I have a controller which return a value of preference with user id and key parameter.

[Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28v8o.png)

Next is the service. This is where my problems begin. I've tested a lot of calls from the jpa repository that I've commented on.

[Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKBkq.png)

Here the repository :

[Repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Sjyc.png)

The preference I want to retrieve from the database is:

- Preference key: LANGUAGE
- Preference user id: 1
- Preference value : fr

Now the request I used in postman :

[Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qa6s6.png)

And here's the mistake with the request Hibernate made.
I don't get it. It duplicates the fields and also it doesn't use the embedded id field (it doesn't do "preference.preferenceId.user.userId" and "preference.preferenceId.key").

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCaz9.png)

What'd I miss? What did I do wrong? I've looked it all up on the internet, I've tested everything, I just can't do it...
Otherwise, I used "Embeddedid" instead of "IdClass" to avoid duplicating the getters and setters.

Thanks to you guys.

Comment: Hi, 
Can you post the full stack excepion? Looking at the StackOverflowException, it is more like a cycled relationship between User and preference. The error is happening inside 'getEntityById' on the first line on the controller and trying to resolve the Lazy OneToMany? I particularly prefer @IdClass instead of @EmbededId/Embedable as well

Comment: I do not think it is a good idea to have `@ManyToOne User user` inside the `PreferenceId`.

Comment: Please post the code not picutres

Comment: If you have the code on github as well or gist, it would help too for us to reproduce, thanks.

Comment: I update the post and add the code instead of pictures. Indeed, when I display in debug the user, there is an exception. I think it's a bad loop... How can I solved it ? Maybe I should use IdClass.

Comment: I have still the bug with id class ! Any help please ?